# Unexpected behavior adding stringified integer to decimal in js

Tags: javascript

I had a strange bug that I just found the source of in my code.

```
"1" + .88 // 10.88
```

What's going on here?

Comment: More accurately, it's `"10.88"`, not `10.88`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When adding a number and a string (whatever their order), the number is converted to a string and then the two are [concatenated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()).

```
.88.toString()
```

is

```
"0.88"
```

So you get the string

```
"10.88"
```

which appears as

```
10.88
```

in most contexts (for example in an HTML input).

---

If you want a specification based analysis, it starts [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) with

[image]

Then the number to string conversion with the leading `0.`is described [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type):
[image]
(s=88, k=2, n=0)

Comment: but why 1 is converted to 10 in his case?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov It's not, the `0` is coming from `.88`.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's the same for the addition: when one of the operands is a string, the other is converted to a string, whatever the order.